# printf char array in structure also prints next int in C

Tags: c

I am very new to C and I don't know that much about it, although I do have some experience with programming as a whole. Whenever I get warnings or errors I just look it up online. But this one doesn't give a warning or an error. It runs fine but it gives the wrong result.

So I have a structure with a char[16] and 2 ints:

```
struct tile {
char layout[16];
int arrowClr;
int spPlacing;
};
```

I make an array of 200 of them with `struct tile tiles[200];`. Then I open a file with a list of characters & numbers:

```
char resourceName[5];
scanf("%s",&*resourceName);

char rLoc[100];
sprintf(rLoc,"Resources/%s/",resourceName);

char tileLoc[100];
sprintf(tileLoc,"%sTiles.txt",rLoc);
FILE *tile_list;
tile_list = fopen(tileLoc,"r");
```

This is the list:

```
   w s d   d   w20
wwwww   w s w  w10
w  wws ww  ww  w10
w  ww  ww sww  w10
   w  sw   w   w20
ws ww  ww  ww  w21
wwww     w  w  w10
ws  w   w   w   20
wwwww   w  sw   20
w  ww  dws dw  w10
wwww  s         20
w  ww sww  ww  w11
wwww   w s w   w20
wddw  sw   w   w10
wwww    s       20
w  wd swd  ww  w20
w  w  s     w  w20
wddww   w s w   20
wddww sww  ww  w20
w  ww  wws ww  w10
wwww   w   ww  w10
```

After that, I cycle through each line, storing the 16 first characters in the structure layout char (I used sprintf to make it know it was a character, because otherwise it just gave ascii value) and the last two numbers in the two ints:

```
for (int i=0;fgets(buf,100,tile_list)!=NULL;i++) {
strtok(buf,"\n");
//printf("%s",buf);
//printf("%c\n",buf[0]);
for (int e=0;e<16;e++) {
    sprintf(&tiles[i].layout[e],"%c",buf[e]);
}
tiles[i].arrowClr = buf[16];
tiles[i].spPlacing = buf[17];
}
```

Then, I display each of them to test it (without the two ints) with:

```
for (int i=0;i<21;i++) {
printf("%s\n",tiles[i].layout);
}
```

And this is the result:

```
   w s d   d   w2
wwwww   w s w  w1
w  wws ww  ww  w1
w  ww  ww sww  w1
   w  sw   w   w2
ws ww  ww  ww  w2
wwww     w  w  w1
ws  w   w   w   2
wwwww   w  sw   2
w  ww  dws dw  w1
wwww  s         2
w  ww sww  ww  w1
wwww   w s w   w2
wddw  sw   w   w1
wwww    s       2
w  wd swd  ww  w2
w  w  s     w  w2
wddww   w s w   2
wddww sww  ww  w2
w  ww  wws ww  w1
wwww   w   ww  w1
```

Removing the `tiles[i].arrowClr = buf[16];` makes that last number disappear from each line, and making the for loop before it go while `e<15` instead of `e<16` makes it disappear too, also making the last character before it vanish too.

BTW I know `tiles[i].arrowClr = buf[16];` & `tiles[i].spPlacing = buf[17];` give me the ascii values of the numbers, that's just another problem, if anybody knows how to fix that too that would be useful

Comment: You are specifying a formatter for a string (C string) to printf.  The expected string should contain a terminating null at the end.  But your layout field does not contain one.

Comment: I'm really surprised at how fast I got an answer. I usually need to wait a few days to get answers on forums. Is it because Stack Overflow is just really popular?

Comment: It's more than popularity. Something about the structure leads to quality answers.  I think developers get a mental boost when providing a good accepted answer. Reputation points function like a score, to an extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
printf("%s\n",tiles[i].layout);
```

there is expected to be a string terminator `'\0'` at the end of the string. But you didn't put one. You built the string like this

```
for (int e=0;e<16;e++) {
    sprintf(&tiles[i].layout[e],"%c",buf[e]);
    ...
```

Your struct definition needs an extra char length

```
char layout[17];        // <--- 16 to 17
```

and then after copying chars from the file, you need

```
tiles[i].layout[16] = '\0';
```

to terminate the string so you can print it.

Then, the last two fields which you obtain with

```
tiles[i].arrowClr = buf[16];
tiles[i].spPlacing = buf[17];
```

should be like this, to convert the single digit ASCII value to an `int` type

```
tiles[i].arrowClr = buf[16] - '0';
tiles[i].spPlacing = buf[17] - '0';
```

asuming that you intended the read value to be the number `1` or `2` and not the character `'1'` or `'2'`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not null terminating the layout string. If this string is has
   16 characters, add one to the layout array for the null. `layout[16]
   = '\0'`
2. You need to convert ASCII strings to numbers if that is your intent. `arrowClr = buf[16] - '0';`

Comment: @technosaurus My answer asked the person to add one to the array for the null. If done the size of layout is now 17. 0..16.

Comment: Presumably you mean "aren't" rather than "are". Please proofread your answers, especially for mistakes that invert meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As I and others mentioned, you need to allocate at least one more byte to your string.  But I would also recommend replacing your for loop (%c) with a simple call to `snprintf()`.  That will let you specify the 16 bytes you want from `buf`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a nul character (`'\0'`) at the end of your string if you want to use it with standard C string functions.

Arrays in C don't have any length information associated with them, so in order for `printf` to know when it's reached the end of a string it needs some sort of marker.  The nul character is used for this (also by all other string related functions like `strlen`, `strcpy`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `layout` field as an array of characters, but you're trying to print it as a string.  In C a string is a NULL terminated array of characters.  Since your array doesn't have a NULL terminator, `printf` keeps looking until it finds a 0 byte, which it ends up finding in the `arrowClr` field which is laid out next in memory.  That's why it's printing out the number.

You need to either make `layout` one character bigger, i.e. `char layout[17]`, and set `layout[16] = 0`, or you would need to run `printf` in a loop to print each character individually.  I'd recommend the former.

To get the numerical values of the last two characters, you need to do this:

```
tiles[i].arrowClr = buf[16] - '0';
tiles[i].spPlacing = buf[17] - '0';
```

Comment: `atoi()` needs a string, not a char.  It's a good idea, though.  Library calls are better supported (and portable), generally.